# Does nvarchar() negatively affect SQL execution time?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

My query is

```
select * 
from Database.dbo.table 
order by EquipmentID asc
```

`table` has 445,000 rows and the following columns:

```
Date (datetime, null)
EquipmentID (nvarchar(20), null)
Filename (nvarchar(200), null)
Linenumber (int, null)
ErrorCode (nvarchar(20), null)
Description (nvarchar(max), null)
```

This statement above is taking 13-30 minutes to execute. I thought that it was related to network connection but another person ran the same query in under 13 seconds from the same location.

The database is hosted by AWS. And this may be attributed to network connection issues. But I'm wondering if there is something about my `nvarchar(MAX)` or other column architecture that could improve my performance just at a glance by someone who knows more than I do about this sort of thing?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, if two users are seeing performance variance of that magnitude on the same query, it has nothing to do with the underlying table structure.

Comment: If you want to test the impact of the LOB column, try running the same query without the description column.   Sorting LOBs usually implies copying them around in queries which can take time.

Comment: If your querying against a `varchar` and using an `nvarchar` against it in the `WHERE` it can have significant performance problems (i.e. `VarcharColumn = N'Nvarchar Literal'`), however, although an `nvarchar` is *double* the size of a `varchar` if you have a well indexed table for the query, there will be little difference in the performance of querying a `varchar` and an `nvarchar`; reading the data is going to be the more expensive part and the impact will only be more noticable with very large (in size) data sets. Seems like the queries is the problem in my opinion.

Comment: Considering that one of the columns is called `EquipmentID`, I wonder if it has numerical data (as it's an ID), and one person is using a query like `WHERE EquipmentID IN (N'123',N'456')` while the other `WHERE EquipmentID IN (123, 456)`. If so, the latter would very likely perform significantly worse.